# MAU calculation how it works

Tags: twitter-fabric

We have integrated `crashlytics` in one of our mobile application and it has been working good till now.

I have couple of question related to its display of MAU (monthly active users).

1. How do you guys calculate this. Is it based on number of unique devices on which app was active in last month or is it unique number of users?
2. Also how do you define a user/device to be active for a month?

Any insights into this would be helpful as we are getting the same values from a different source as well and 2 are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

For reference, Answers metrics are defined here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-metrics.html#monthly-active-users

1) MAU is defined as the number of unique app installations across all devices that were active over the trailing 30-day period. Note: Foreground activity must happen for a device to be active.

2) A user is active if the app was launched on their device and brought to the foreground for a day in the past 30 rolling days.